# Slow page load (seemingly large pulls from MariaDB)

Tags: database

We have a Drupal 8 site running on Windows/Apache/PHP7.2 that pulls data from a MariaDB server (on a different subnet - ie not in our DMZ) also running Windows. When a user is signed in to Drupal the pages load really slowly, looking at the firewall traffic between the drupal host and DB host during sign-in we're getting transfers weighing in between 1.5 MB and 18 MB. This to me seems excessive but as I am unfamiliar with Drupal can't say for certain.

One of our Dev team is adamant the issue is because the host is running Windows, we believe the slow page loads is due to the amount of data being pulled/processed - we would love to hear any experiences/opinions any of may have.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Windows networking is slower than Linux.  Here's a study that show this:

https://www.principledtechnologies.com/Red%20Hat/RHEL6_network_0613.pdf

I think the underlying problem is that Windows sockets have a lot more overhead than Linux sockets do.  So opening connections in Windows takes longer.  Applications that are built for Linux often assume opening and closing sockets is quick and this can slow down performance on Windows.

That said, there are also a lot of differences in tuning Apache and MariaDB on windows.  Linux has lightweight thread management and Windows doesn't.  I seem to remember Linux has a few httpd processes that handle a bunch of threads while Windows may need a lot of separate larger processes to handle multiple connections.  I believe there are similar settings for MariaDB as well.  Do some searches on optimizing these under windows.

By default windows sticks a lot of cached information in the database, with a separate server, you may have some latency issues slowing things down while the cache info is retrieved.  You may want to look at using APCu and Memcache to move this caching into your DMZ.  This is not a security risk since these are all things that are going to be displayed via the webserver.  There is lots of information on configuring these on the net.

Finally, you might consider using a front end cache agent.  Varnish is not hard to set up or CloudFlare can supply a lot of this for free.

Comment: Definitely look to Memcache/Wincache first and see if this alleviates the issue.